How can I use a Replace field in JOIN comparison field
I have an SQL statement that is not allowing me to use the converted field name from a Replace.  I need to use the converted field for my Join statement.
This is the SQL code that I am using, but what I want to use is Referto.  When I try this, I get the error that this is an invalid field.
 SELECT
       REF.[OmOrdID] AS Order_ID
      ,REGM.VisitID  AS Visit_ID
      ,REGM.AccountNumber AS Account_number
      ,HIMM.Name AS Patient_name
          ,REF.[RowUpdateDateTime] AS Date_order_entered
      ,REPLACE (REPLACE(ReferTo,'[MisPhDirContact]',' '), '[MisPerson]',' ') AS Referto
              ,[ReferralStartDate] AS Referral_date
      ,OrderProvider    AS Ordering_provider
   FROM livefdb.dbo.OmOrd_Referral REF
   LEFT JOIN livefdb.dbo.OmOrd_Main ORDM ON (REF.OmOrdID      = ORDM.OmOrdID)
       JOIN livefdb.dbo.OmOrd_Main2 ORDM2 ON (REF.OmOrdID    = ORDM2.OmOrdID)
       JOIN livefdb.dbo.RegAcct_Main REGM ON (ORDM.VisitID   = REGM.VisitID)
       JOIN livefdb.dbo.HimRec_Main HIMM ON  (REGM.PatientID  = HIMM.PatientID)
       JOIN livefdb.dbo.MisPerson_Main PER ON (ReferTo        = PER.UnvUserID)

   WHERE REF.RowUpdateDateTime > '2023-01-01 00:00:00.000' and REF.RowUpdateDateTime <  
    '2024-01-01 00:00:00.000' and ReferTo IS NOT NULL 


what sql flavor?

Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

The problem with your query is that it is not possible to reference a dynamically generated field in a JOIN, so you have a few options (not trying to be exhaustive):
1. Repeat the same transformation on the JOIN clause:
    JOIN livefdb.dbo.MisPerson_Main PER ON (REPLACE (REPLACE(ReferTo,'[MisPhDirContact]',' '), '[MisPerson]',' ') = PER.UnvUserID)


Use a CTE to query the main data and JOIN the CTE instead:

WITH REF AS (
    SELECT
       REF.[OmOrdID] AS Order_ID
      ,REGM.VisitID  AS Visit_ID
      ,REGM.AccountNumber AS Account_number
      ,HIMM.Name AS Patient_name
          ,REF.[RowUpdateDateTime] AS Date_order_entered
      ,REPLACE (REPLACE(ReferTo,'[MisPhDirContact]',' '), '[MisPerson]',' ') AS ReferTo
              ,[ReferralStartDate] AS Referral_date
      ,OrderProvider    AS Ordering_provider
   FROM OmOrd_Referral REF
   LEFT JOIN OmOrd_Main ORDM ON (REF.OmOrdID      = ORDM.OmOrdID)
       JOIN OmOrd_Main2 ORDM2 ON (REF.OmOrdID    = ORDM2.OmOrdID)
       JOIN RegAcct_Main REGM ON (ORDM.VisitID   = REGM.VisitID)
       JOIN HimRec_Main HIMM ON  (REGM.PatientID  = HIMM.PatientID)
   
   WHERE
       REF.RowUpdateDateTime > '2023-01-01 00:00:00.000'
       AND REF.RowUpdateDateTime < '2024-01-01 00:00:00.000'
       AND REF.ReferTo IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT REF.*
FROM REF
    JOIN MisPerson_Main PER ON ReferTo = PER.UnvUserID;

A subquery could also work instead, but a CTE is much cleaner.
The second method works because the value get "materialized" in the "temporary table" (the CTE), what makes it possible to use that data in JOINs.

Assuming you have field ReferTo in table which you are using in REPLACE function REPLACE (REPLACE(ReferTo,'[MisPhDirContact]',' '), '[MisPerson]',' ')
Try this
SELECT 
       REF.[OmOrdID] AS Order_ID 

      ,REGM.VisitID  AS Visit_ID
      ,REGM.AccountNumber AS Account_number
      ,HIMM.Name AS Patient_name
          ,REF.[RowUpdateDateTime] AS Date_order_entered
      ,REPLACE (REPLACE(ReferTo,'[MisPhDirContact]',' '), '[MisPerson]',' ') AS Referto ,[ReferralStartDate] AS Referral_date
      ,OrderProvider    AS Ordering_provider
   FROM livefdb.dbo.OmOrd_Referral REF
   LEFT JOIN livefdb.dbo.OmOrd_Main ORDM ON (REF.OmOrdID      = ORDM.OmOrdID)
      JOIN livefdb.dbo.OmOrd_Main2 ORDM2 ON (REF.OmOrdID    = ORDM2.OmOrdID)
       JOIN livefdb.dbo.RegAcct_Main REGM ON (ORDM.VisitID   = REGM.VisitID)
       JOIN livefdb.dbo.HimRec_Main HIMM ON  (REGM.PatientID  = HIMM.PatientID)
       JOIN livefdb.dbo.MisPerson_Main PER ON (ReferTo        = PER.UnvUserID)

   WHERE REF.RowUpdateDateTime > '2023-01-01 00:00:00.000' and REF.RowUpdateDateTime <  
    '2024-01-01 00:00:00.000' and 
REPLACE (REPLACE(ReferTo,'[MisPhDirContact]',' '), '[MisPerson]',' ') IS NOT NULL   


For me the cleanest approach to add a computed column like a variable in procedural coding is APPLY
SELECT
   REF.[OmOrdID] AS Order_ID
  ,REGM.VisitID  AS Visit_ID
  ,REGM.AccountNumber AS Account_number
  ,HIMM.Name AS Patient_name
  ,REF.[RowUpdateDateTime] AS Date_order_entered
  ,myApply.Referto
  ,REF.[ReferralStartDate] AS Referral_date
  ,OrderProvider AS Ordering_provider
FROM livefdb.dbo.OmOrd_Referral REF
CROSS APPLY(SELECT REPLACE (REPLACE(REF.ReferTo,'[MisPhDirContact]',' '), '[MisPerson]',' ') AS Referto) myApply
LEFT JOIN livefdb.dbo.OmOrd_Main ORDM ON (REF.OmOrdID        = ORDM.OmOrdID)
     JOIN livefdb.dbo.OmOrd_Main2 ORDM2 ON (REF.OmOrdID      = ORDM2.OmOrdID)
     JOIN livefdb.dbo.RegAcct_Main REGM ON (ORDM.VisitID     = REGM.VisitID)
     JOIN livefdb.dbo.HimRec_Main HIMM ON  (REGM.PatientID   = HIMM.PatientID)
     JOIN livefdb.dbo.MisPerson_Main PER ON (myApply.ReferTo = PER.UnvUserID)

WHERE REF.RowUpdateDateTime > '2023-01-01 00:00:00.000' and REF.RowUpdateDateTime < '2024-01-01 00:00:00.000' and myApply.ReferTo IS NOT NULL 

The idea in short:

We use 'CROSS APPLY' with SELECT to create additional columns with an alias (in this case myApply) and a column name. If you use a unique column name it might be better in terms of ambiguity.
We use the column myApply.ReferTo in all places we need it.

